# How To Add Multiple Clickable Links in a Gmail Signature

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I have an image of a signature that I'd like to add as my Gmail signature. That very image contains two small icons, LinkedIn and a globe (for my website). Now, what I want is the ability to add the link to my LinkedIn profile to the LinkedIn icon and the link to my website to the globe. Till now, I've only been able to add *one* link to the *whole* image. Is there a way to add two links to two different parts of an image, and use that as a Gmail signature?

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach two separate links to the same image. The HTML `<img>` tag can't be split that way.

To add a link to each icon, you would have to break the image up into two distinct images, upload them, and attach the correct link to each one.

Comment: Does `<map>` work in a Gmail signature?

Comment: Ah, I tried that, but the thing is when uploading two seperate images (which in my case would be the broken up parts of the original image), Gmail's signature box doesn't allow me to freely place them and therefore doesn't allow them to look like the original image. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: @DhruvErry How did you want them positioned? You can put them next to each other, but you probably won't be able to position them vertically and split the links.

Comment: @ale It doesn't work if you try inserting it as text; Gmail doesn't seem to render HTML elements (except maybe a few basic ones). If you could copy the rendered map element, there may be a way to make it work, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

To make your signature compatible with most of the email providers is to split the image and use the generated images in html `tables` and use inline css for styling.

`map` element can put multiple links on one image but is not compatible with all the email providers.